# Workday REST API access to base64 photo/image data

Tags: api, rest, workday-api

I have successfully used the /workers REST api as well as the /data api to get information about the worker(s) that I am interested in, including a photo block similar to this:

```
"photo": {
    "descriptor": "Employee's Photo (~~~~~~~)",
    "id": "12345~~~~~54321"
},
```

I am now wondering whether there is a REST api endpoint to access the base64 data for this photo so that I can download, scale down and cache for future use in our web application?

I did find some documentation for a few SOAP endpoints (Get_Employee_Image, Get_Workers_Photos) but wondering if there is a REST endpoint to access this data. I guess another option would be a WQL statement to access the base64 photo data if that is possible using the /data endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like the delivered REST endpoints have the photo base64 data. You could create a report within Workday, make it web service enabled, and then call it like a REST API.

Or, you could go with the SOAP endpoints you mentioned. The Get_Workers SOAP API also has an Include_Photo option in the Response group.